# Is it possible to create a custom widget on the Sitefinity 10 dashboard?

Tags: c#, telerik, dashboard, sitefinity

I was wondering whether it is possible to create a custom widget on the Sitefinity 10 dashboard.

I have tried to add a widget from the 'Configure Dashboard widgets' section.

I can get a dashboard widget that lists all my dynamic module items. But I need a way to filter these down further by their custom property 'ReviewDate' (DateTime) whilst still retaining the out of the box functionality associated with dashboard widgets (for example the paging, direct inline edit links), I can't get access to this property from the dashboard service, it only returns generic properties such as title, published date etc.

Is there an alternative way to achieve the above?

I could not find any reliable source, so not sure... Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard widgets, it is the same as front-end widgets. All what you need to do is:

1. Create controller
2. Add attribute `[ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "Dashboard Sample", Title = "Dashboard Sample", SectionName = "Custom (Administration)")]`
3. Add view for your widget:

> <div class="sfDashboardWidgetWrp">
>         <h2 class="sfBlack">Widget name   </h2>     <div class="dataWrapper">         <!-- ENTER YOUR MARKUP HERE-->
>     </div>
>       </div>

4. Open `\App_Data\Sitefinity\Configuration\ToolboxesConfig.config`. Find `<add enabled="True" title="Custom (Administration)" ordinal="0" name="Custom (Administration)">` and add `tags="backend"`. It should be like that `<add enabled="True" title="Custom (Administration)" ordinal="0" name="Custom (Administration)" tags="backend">`

After that, if you will go to `Configure Dashboard widgets`, you will find section with your widget:
[image]

Comment: Hi again Victor, yes I understand your post, but what I am trying to do is get a custom field out, I know I can do this like any other MVC widget, what I need is the functionality of the other admin content listing widgets as they include Kendo features like direct inline editing and paging etc. But if I try to add this functionality into my widget I then can't pull in custom fields from my dynamic module type. Does this make sense?

Comment: You mean, you want to show you custom fields in content listing page?

Comment: No, see this link: http://docs.sitefinity.com/recent-items, it has a recent items dashboard widget. I know how to create a dashboard widget similar to this and I can filter it down to show only my custom module type instead of all content. But  what I also need to do is have all this functionality and also filter my dynamic items by a custom datetime property, does that make sense?

Comment: I think in this case you need to build completely separate widget. You can take source code of "Recent Items" widget and tune it a bit. Plus you need to build another service, which should be similar to /Sitefinity/Services/Dashboard/DashboardService.svc/GetRecentItems/ but should contain all necessary for you fields

Comment: If it is not so urgent for you, i can try to build it on the weekend and open-source it

Comment: Thank you very much Victor. It is for a commercial project a very large build. But I only have two months experience with Sitefinity so I appreciate you sharing your expertise. I am fine with MVC widgets etc. You don't need to try and build it I will accept your answer as you have been a massive help with all my Sitefinity queries and at least now I know the kind of work involved as this feature was heavily underestimated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the filter expression of the dynamic content widget, through the Advnaced widget settings. If you use the MVC widget, you can find this setting under Advanced > Model:
[image]

If you are using the WebForms widget, the same setting is burried under several layers of settings:
[image]

More details about filter expressions: http://docs.sitefinity.com/filter-expressions-for-content-items